# Is this a diode or a resistor? What is the equivalent of this one in the picture?

Tags: resistors, diodes

[image: unknown component]

[image: unknown component]

Is this a diode or a resistor? I am unable to solve this problem of my PCB inverter.

---

[image]

That is the back of the component... pls guide me...

Comment: don't make an assumption that it is either a diode or a resistor

Comment: Sparkgap arrestor.

Comment: @Analog Kid's answer almost certainly tells you what you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

SA could refer to a Surge Arrestor, like a TransZorb, although I don't recall seeing one in a glass package.  It could be a super-fast, low energy type used to protect signal and data lines.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/88301/15ke.pdf

---

Better:

Top: Original image

Middle - ["Axial magneto DSS-30IL-A22R"](https://lispol.com/produkty/iskrownik-osiowy-dss-30il-a22r-dss-30il-a22r)

Bottom: (Mitsubishi?)  SPG/ Spark Gap Protectors/ GGDT 3600V Glass gas discharge tube DA53-302M [from](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/SPG-Spark-Gap-Protectors-GGDT-3600V_1600090523018.html?)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The blue band matches with a [Mitsubishi DSS-601M](https://www.mmc.co.jp/adv/dev/english/pdf/Division_PDF/dss.pdf) surge absorger. See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657917/rookie-needing-help-identifying-components/) for pictures of the similar Mitsubishi DSP-Series.

[image]